# Moving daily Snapshot Data from AWS S3 to AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Have a daily snapshot data that gets dumped into AWS S3 bucket. Each day's data file is build on top of previous day's file.
I want to move this incremental data into AWS Athena without duplicating previous day's data.

I learned that AWS Glue can be a handy tool to move data into Athena on daily basis. but I am not sure how can i do it without duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean by "Each day's data file is build on top of previous day's file"?

Comment: If yesterday’s file had 5000 entries and today 150 entries were logged. Today’s file will have 5150 entries.

Answer (score 2):

When a table is defined in Amazon Athena (or AWS Glue), a `location` is provided that tells Athena where to look in Amazon S3 for the data.

This is conceptually different to a traditional database where data needs to be 'loaded'. **No data needs to be 'loaded' or 'moved into' Amazon Athena** -- it simply looks in the specified location and uses whatever data files it sees in that location (and any subdirectories).

If you are producing **incremental files** each day, then you can simply add additional files in that S3 location (making sure the filenames do not clash with existing files). Then, when a query is next run in Amazon Athena, those files will be included in the data that is scanned.

However, if you are producing a **daily file with *all* data**, then simply **replace the previous file** with the new file. Athena will use whatever file is in that location when running a query.